# Run the latest Mathematica version without installing it

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Is the solution just running mathematica on wolfram alpha? If so, how can one run a or part of a .nb code on wolfram alpha? I only know how to run a single line of code on it.

Comment: How about using https://www.wolframcloud.com/ instead?

Comment: I had asked Wolfram support how to execute short lines of Mathematica code in Wolfram Alpha. Their answer is generally you can not. I tried anyway. My experience matches their answer. Now, when have a need to run a bit of Mathematica code. There are basic, very limited, free accounts.